# How to make LIKE behave case-insensitive?

Tags: abap, case-insensitive, opensql

I have an `importedParameter` which I want to search inside of a column in a `SELECT`.

But for now it is case-sensitive, how can I make it **case-insensitive** ?

I've tried multiple things: `AND LOWER(columnName) LIKE LOWER(@lv_string)` or `AND columnName LIKE @tst_string COLLATE utf8_general_ci` and some other stuff but got this error:

> A Boolean expression is required in positions starting with LOWER(Q.

**Sample code:**

```
DATA(tst_string) = '%' && importedParamter && '%'.

IF anotherParameter IS NOT INITIAL.
  IF importedParamter IS NOT INITIAL.
    SELECT * FROM <table1> as p
      INNER JOIN <table2> as q on q~column1 = p~column1
      WHERE p~column2 = @anotherParameter
      AND q~column2 LIKE @tst_string
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @anotherName
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: So `AND LOWER( q~column2 ) LIKE @tst_string` did not work? Did this cause an error or did it just not work?

Comment: Also, what SAP_BASIS release are you using? There were some considerable additions to OpenSQL in recent releases, but not everyone is using those yet.

Comment: ```A Boolean expression is required in positions starting with LOWER(Q.``` - this is my syntax error. For trying it with LOWER

Comment: I might have a solution for you, but it requires SAP_BASIS 7.51. Can you confirm that you have at least that release?

Comment: Yes, confirmed. thanks for trying helping me out!

Comment: The answer I posted is not the one I had in mind (using a `WITH...SELECT`), but a far simpler one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM adrp
  WHERE LOWER( name_first ) LIKE 'phi%'
  INTO TABLE @DATA(results).
```

It finds my personal data entry (as well as those of another "Philipp" and of a "Philip"), even though we are all spelled with a capital `P`.

`LIKE LOWER( 'Phi%' )` does not work, but when you can't control the input, then you can convert it to lower case before the select:

```
DATA(tst_string) = 'Phi%'.
TRANSLATE tst_string TO LOWER CASE.
SELECT *
  FROM adrp
  WHERE LOWER( name_first ) LIKE @tst_string
  INTO TABLE @DATA(results).
```

Release: 7.54

I am not sure which release specifically allowed functions like LOWER within the WHERE clause. According to the comments, it should work since 7.51.

Comment: `LOWER` was added in ABAP 7.51.

Comment: @SandraRossi Does that include the use within the WHERE-clause? I believe that there was a time where the column-list allowed a lot more functions than were allowed in WHERE or ON. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: Note sure if you mean that SQL functions are permitted on the left side of the WHERE clause since [ABAP 7.50](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-750-open_sql.htm) ("Left side of any WHERE condition").

Answer (score 3):

I believe Regex is your preferred choice: [`LIKE_REGEXPR`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_string_func.htm):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM <table1> as p
 INNER JOIN <table2> as q on q~column1 = p~column1
 WHERE p~column2 = @anotherParameter
   AND like_regexpr( pcre = '\bparam\b', value = q~column2, CASE_SENSITIVE = 'X' ) = '1'
  INTO TABLE DATA(@anotherName).
```

It has `CASE_SENSITIVE` predicate which respects (or not) the case.

Though this is available only [since ABAP 7.55](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/abennews-755-abap_sql.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_19@19@), so on lower releases you are out of the luck.

Comment: ha, just learnt something... Thanks Suncatcher...